# What is the best way to force browser to load fresh file in script tag

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to force browser to load fresh file in script tag?

Comment: Probably configuring the server to deny caching of that file.

Comment: take a look at .htaccess settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define version variable which always should be updated with `filename.js?versionvalue`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?$$REVISION$$"></script>
```